# Re-order ruby array

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby array:

```
["A", "C", "B", "D", "F", "E"]
```

User will supply an input, e.g.

```
input = "B"
```

I want to shift the values in the array, so the first item of the array equals `input`, and get the result of a new array:

```
["B", "D", "F", "E", "A", "C"]
```

User will be choosing from a dropdown options, so they can only choose the letters from original array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Array#rotate`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-rotate).

```
arr = ["A", "C", "B", "D", "F", "E"]

arr.rotate(arr.index('B'))
 #=> ["B", "D", "F", "E", "A", "C"]
```